# List filter based on another columns values

Tags: list, list-view

I have 1 `'EMPLOYEE LIST'` with many items.

I also have lists:

- Group A: {item A1, item A2, item A3}
- Group B: {item B1, item B2, item B3, item B4, item B5}
- Group C: {item C1, item C2....}

Now I want to create separate pages A, B & C which will display above `'EMPLOYEE LIST'` filtered with only items from Group A/B/C respectively.

**e.g.** Page A will only show items from 'EMPLOYEE LIST' which items are present in Group A etc.

Answer (score 1):

when you create your list view on `Group By` section you choose your columns you want to be viewed 
[image]

Comment: No Melad, Group by only works for that list items columns and for columns from another list.

Comment: oohh, sorry I thought it was one list and you need to create a different views... but now I Read your Question carefully... you've 3 lists and you need to link them on the "Employee List"